# VB2010 Extract specific characters out of array string

Tags: arrays, vb.net, character, extract, point

Is there a way to specify which characters I want to pull out of an array string?
This is not, code below, the forum just didn't like it as text.

```
For example:  abc1234blahblah  and I want to point from the left, characters [4-7] 
Character 4 = "1"
Character 5 = "2"
Character 6 = "3"
Character 7 = "4"
```

Then I'd like to put those into a string: "1234"

True application I'm working on, a filepath has the first directory always start with the project number, so I want to pull the job number and put it into a textbox in VB 2010.
Example: Q:\2456_customer_name....\file.xls
I want to be able to again point to the numbers, but if I know that the main directory will always start with the job number, then I should be able to just point to characters [4-7] and put it in a string.  I think I know the concept, but don't know VB well enough to put it together.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular expression would work

```
Dim numRegex As New Regex("\d+")
Dim number As String = numRegex.Match("abc1234blahblah").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Substring function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swz0961t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim a = "abc1234blahblah"
Dim b = a.Substring(3, 4) ' b now contains "1234"
```

Thinking about it more, could it be possible for the drive the file is on to be a UNC path like `\\MyServer\SomeShare\9876_CustomerName\file.xls`? If so, extracting the number would be a bit more tricky. I tried to account for all possible ways of specifying the file:

```
Module Module1

    Function GetCustomerNumber(filename As String) As String
        Dim abspath = IO.Path.GetFullPath(filename)
        Dim dir = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(abspath)
        Dim fileParentDirectory = dir.Split(IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last
        Return fileParentDirectory.Substring(0, 4)
    End Function

    Sub Main()

        Dim a = "C:\5678_CustomerName\file.xls"
        Dim b = "\\se1234\Share001\5678_CustomerName\file.xls"
        Dim c = "\5678_CustomerName\file.xls"
        Dim d = ".\5678_CustomerName\file.xls"
        Dim e = "5678_CustomerName\file.xls"
        Console.WriteLine(GetCustomerNumber(a))
        Console.WriteLine(GetCustomerNumber(b))
        Console.WriteLine(GetCustomerNumber(c))
        Console.WriteLine(GetCustomerNumber(d))
        Console.WriteLine(GetCustomerNumber(e))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Which outputs "5678" for all of the examples.